# What is wrong with sizeof program

Tags: c, char, int, sizeof

I have made a program to display the number of bytes required to store values of type int and type char using the sizeof operator.  However, it does not compile, it says 'Id returned 1 exit status'.  How do I fix this?

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int num, num1;

    num = sizeof(int);
    num1 = sizeof(char);
    printf("Bytes required for int:  %d   Bytes required for char: %d\n", num, num1);
    getchar();
}
```

Thank you

Comment: after `getchar();` and before `}` , add a line `return 0;`, `main()` function should return termination status that is `int`-- so this warning appearing.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan I don't think that's the problem, but then again I don't know what it is either

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan You probably read it incorrect.  OP says `it does not compile`.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan That's not the problem it still doesn't work

Comment: @Paul Filch - how are you compiling it?

Comment: Not the problem either, but you should match format and arguments of `printf()` with, say, `printf("… %d … %d\n", (int)num, (int)num1);` (many other solutions are possible).

Comment: What do you mean?  I press the compile button.

Comment: @PaulFilch first add `int` before `main()` then again compile and run also remove function `getchar();`

Comment: Is that the full error message ?

Comment: It also says Permission denied above the `Id returned 1 status` message

Comment: Permission denied? Maybe you're already running the program and the compiler has problems writing the executable, because it's open.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan I tried that, still does not work

Comment: @PaulFilch what exactly error you gets, which compiler is you are using ?

Comment: @PaulFilch Which is odd because it does work: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=f12d68d2388567dcda773831985aa82b-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51

Comment: You mean `ld` right? Not `Id`?

Comment: @PaulFilch check its [working here](http://ideone.com/nvbxwE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is correct, perhaps you can try to copy the code and paste it on a new file, and delete the old one.  I hope this works :)

Answer (score 1):

I could run it, try here: http://www.compileonline.com/compile_c_online.php
Or you could compile it this way : $gcc main.c -o demo -lm -pthread -lgmp -lreadline 2>&1
Result that I obtain:

Bytes required for int:  4   Bytes required for char: 1

Answer (score 1):

This code is correct only. It has no problem.
Check that on ideone.

```
# 1:   hide   clone   input   7 seconds ago

result: Runtime error       time: 0s    memory: 2252 kB     signal: -1
input: no
output:

Bytes required for int:  4   Bytes required for char: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the standard format for your main function which can be:

```
int main() {
     //your code
     return 0;
}
```

Which will result in the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int num, num1;

    num = sizeof(int);
    num1 = sizeof(char);
    printf("Bytes required for int:  %d   Bytes required for char: %d\n", num, num1);
    return 0;
}
```

This compiles in GCC4.7.2 ([here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=f12d68d2388567dcda773831985aa82b-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51))